# [UNITY]-JS - I Want my gameobject and the traffic light appear at the same time

Tags: javascript

First of all I get this also in here.
I'm using this code for a game object to appear and disappear for a particular time !
Problem :
I have a traffic light with an option of only a green and red and it alternates every 10 seconds.

**I want my gameobject and the traffic light appear at the same time that when my vehicle 
violated the rule** there will be a pop a message that will appear . 
I know the pop up message . :)

```
// make the object invisible
collider.enabled = false;

// make the object visible
collider.enabled = true;

// toggle object's visibility each second
function Update () {

// Find out whether current second is odd or even
var seconds : int = Time.time;
var oddeven = (seconds % 10) == 0;

// Enable renderer accordingly
collider.enabled = oddeven;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That will do the trick:

```
#pragma strict


var frequency = 10.0;
private var lastTimeLoop = 0.0;



function Start () {

}

function Update () {

    if(Time.time - lastTimeLoop > frequency)
    {
        gameObject.renderer.enabled = !gameObject.renderer.enabled;
        lastTimeLoop = Time.time;
    }   

}
```

Comment: my goal is make the cube hide for seconds and appear it again for seconds.

Comment: OK, so instead of the last line of code of your question, which is `collider.enabled = oddeven;`, replace it by `renderer.enabled = oddeven`. Does make sense?

Comment: I want Sir , that when I hide the object for 10 seconds I will appear it again for 10 seconds and loop it hide, appear, hide, appear